# Incomplete download from Store

Tags: 8.1, store, storage, app-update

I was downloading Tiny Troopers 2, but i canceled, now i can't delete the incomplete download. He is allocated on the Others storage.
Specs: Windows Phone 8.1
       Lumia 535

Answer (score 1):

Install the whole application and delete it then from the Start menu.